# Jquery should fire only one event

Tags: jquery

I have written two script one for Enter button click and one for change, but both events are firing, I want if enter button clicked by keyup/keydown/keypress/paste then change should not fire as well on keyup/keydown/keypress/paste only one event should fire.

```
$('#txtName').on('keypress keyup paste', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
        AddName($('#txtName').val());
    }
});  

$('#txtName').on({   
   change: function () { AddName($('#txtName').val()); }
});
```

Comment: `keypress` and `keyup` are both triggered (at different stages) for a single key-stroke. What are you expecting?

Comment: on enter keypress or keyup, either keypress fire or keyup fire and if enter is clicked then change event should not fire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause you are using two events with key listener. Just use one of them `keypress` or `keyup` event.

And add a `event.preventDefault();` for stop the event it will not trigger the `change` event.

```js
$('#txtName').on('keyup paste', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        AddName($('#txtName').val(),e);
        
    }
});  

$('#txtName').on({   
   change: function (e) { AddName($('#txtName').val(),e); }
});

function AddName(value,e)
{
  console.log(e.type+ " - "+value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtName">
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `#txtName` here is an input box, then the `change` event is deferred until the element loses focus and will get triggered if the value has changed from the previous state.

For your requirements, you can combine all the events on `jquery.on` and add your logic in the handler as such:

```
$('#txtName').on('keypress keyup paste change', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (e.type == "change") {
      AddName($('#txtName').val());
    }
     else if (keyCode === 13) {
        AddName($('#txtName').val());
    }
});  

function AddName() {
  // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keypress event fire when user press a key, keyup event is fire when user release the key (after pressing). So you should use either keypress OR keyup, if you want one event fire at a time.